# VMWare route certain http requests through Windows Host

Tags: linux, networking, routing, nat

I am running Ubuntu 18.4 as guest on a Windows 10 host under VMware 15.5.6

Current Network-Connection (Settings->Network Adapter) is set to NAT.

My problem is, that certain http requests **must** (seemingly...) come from the host to be accepted by company servers, i.e. `jira.company.com` (the IPs are static, so I could work with those).

**How can I redirect certain traffic (by URL resp. by IP range, but certainly not *all* on port :80 / :443) to go through (and seemingly originates from) the host PC?**

(Possibly I also make the request headers look IE-Edge-ish, but for that there's [mod headers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj))

note: I can install **anything** in the guest, but **nothing** (i.e. no proxy software) on the host.